# Request between pods on kubernetes returning null

Tags: c#, kubernetes, openshift, httpclient

Hi there I am trying to communicate two aplications (both APIs) in the same cluster on kubernetes(from openshift) but in a different namespace...
When I send the httpclient request using regular URL I get a SSL error because the route "leaves" the internal network and "comes back". With a advice I changed the comunication using my service name (mapped on the pods)... Now I don't get the error but the HTTRESPONSE I gete is Null, with no error or statuscode:
Here is how I configured the service name:

```
http://servicename.projectname.svc.cluster.local:8080/
```

[image: service details]

If i change the port to 8080 or use http I get the error "no route to host" but the route is set. But the HOST field below is set to the URL and not the cluster host, could the problem be this?

[image]

Comment: try `http://service-name.namsespace-name.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: without the port I got "name or service unkown"

Comment: Please include the service/pod configufration in your thread with code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting the certificate in the pipeline (yaml) so it is applied in the pods